# Can't see GRUB menu on boot

Tags: grub, chrome-book

I've installed Ubuntu 15.04 on a Google Pixel 2015 Chromebook, but I can't see the Grub menu. At the time when I should be seeing it, all I see is "Booting from hard disk" and there's some distortion at the top of the screen (it would seem like a few rows of pixels) that lasts exactly the time of Grub menu timeout. So it's like the menu is there, but distorted. If I press a key at that time, the boot process is interrupted: it seems to behave like you'd expect the Grub menu to behave, except I can't see anything.

What could be the problem?

My chromebook uses SeaBIOS (http://www.seabios.org/SeaBIOS) to boot Ubuntu.

**UPDATE: SOLUTION** I am leaving this for those that may encounter the same situation I have. Edit your `/etc/default/grub` and make sure that the following lines are commented out like so:

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

Also it's important that these two lines are uncommented:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

I have a strong suspicion now that the last line was essential in fixing the problem. Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` afterwards.

Comment: If you press a key when you think the Grub menu is showing but distorted, does that stop Linux from booting?

Comment: @Gilles Yes, it seems to behave like you'd expect grub menu to behave, except I can't see anything.

Comment: Edit `/etc/default/grub` and uncomment the line `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`, I think.

Comment: @Gilles I've tried that, didn't work. I'm guessing this problem will be chromebook specific.

Comment: Can we please salvage and re-open this question? SeaBIOS is used as payload for coreboot to boot in legacy mode, which is one of the easier and less invasive options to boot a non-Chrome OS kernel and distribution (see https://mrchromebox.tech/). This is a valid question about configuring Grub on typical distributions, I guess we're just not used to this problem anymore on standard PCs. I'd like to help out if there are open questions.