# Can't see GRUB menu on Boot, Chromebook

Tags: dual-boot, grub, chrome-book

I've installed Arch 2017.07.01 on a micro SD card in my Dell Chromebook 13 using [this guide](http://lifehacker.com/5680453/build-a-killer-customized-arch-linux-installation-and-learn-all-about-linux-in-the-process), and I'm using [John Lewis' SeaBios](https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/) to dual boot. I can successfully get into the boot menuand select the micro sd to boot from, but I then get a `Welcome to GRUB!` message, and, instead of a GRUB console, i get a few lines of white distortion on top of my screen, with the boot menu still frozen in the background. I believe the distortion is the console outputting incorrectly as typing seems to change it, and it disappears after a while, reappearing when i move the mouse or type, like the screen falling asleep and waking up.

I've already tried doing a full reinstall of arch, commenting out `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET`, and changing `GRUB_GFXMODE` to `640x480`, but nothing had worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is very late, but I want to leave an answer in case you still have this problem, or anyone else comes across it. What worked for me was doing everything OP did(commenting out `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET`, uncommenting `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480`), but also uncommenting `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`. For those who don't know know these are all changes in `/etc/default/grub`. After you change that file you always have to run `sudo update-grub`. This worked on the Chromebook Pixel 2 but it might work on other chromebooks as well.

see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205565/cant-see-grub-menu-on-boot) as a reference.